# Using boost on MacOS with MacPorts

Tags: boost, macports, automake

I'm trying to build some software on MacOS that uses boost (specifically boost_system).  It all appears to configure and build ok, but when it goes to link it gives the error:

```
ld: library 'boost_system' not found
```

Looking at the boost libraries that MacPorts installed, they all appear to have a `-mt` suffix -- I find `/opt/local/lib/libboost_system-mt.dylib`.  If I change the Makefile.am file to use `-lboost_system-mt` instead, then everything works, but of course that is both very painful and would break any other build.

Anyone know what is going on here?  Where does this `-mt` suffix come from?  Is this a problem with MacPorts or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-mt` suffix in your Boost library filenames stands for "multithreaded" (as [illustrated in this thread](https://groups.google.com/g/boost-list/c/O4fJxn4OuK4)). That naming convention is used by some package managers, [including MacPorts](https://lists.macports.org/pipermail/macports-users/2013-July/033066.html), to distinguish between single-threaded and multithreaded versions of the Boost libraries.

First option: Instead of editing `Makefile.am` directly, you might be able to pass the correct library name to your build configuration script. That is often done via flags like `LDFLAGS` or `LIBS`.

```bash
LDFLAGS="-lboost_system-mt" ./configure
```

Or: create a symlink from `libboost_system.dylib` to `libboost_system-mt.dylib`. That way, your software can link against `libboost_system` while actually using the multithreaded variant.

```bash
ln -s /opt/local/lib/libboost_system-mt.dylib /opt/local/lib/libboost_system.dylib
```

Comment: The approach of creating the symlink seems the best in that it does not require any changes to the automake package being built or the build process, and seems to work (at least it links and does not appear to have problems at runtime).  It definitely seems like something is missing from the MacPorts boost package.

Comment: @ChrisDodd I agree. That seems to be a design choice (intended to manage different versions of the libraries: single-threaded vs. multithreaded). But it does lead to unexpected complications in the software development process.